# Postscript quits after displaying image within loop

Tags: image, ghostscript, postscript

I'm trying to display an image (a small logo) within a loop in a postscript program executed in Ghostscript. The image is displayed by calling the ImageMagick program using run or runlibfile. Problem is Ghostscript just goes away after correctly displaying the image and associated text once--it never returns to the main program to continue with the loop.  No error messages whatever.  Any ideas on what's up?

Comment: Never mind!  A note in an unrelated post solved the problem:  I removed the reference to Adobe 3.0 in the first line of the ImageMagick code and it works beautifully.

Comment: It is OK to answer you own question, and it is better to do that explicitly (as an answer) than in a comment, since comments may eventually disappear.